# get zero counts by week and group when dataset filtered to zero observations

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a shiny app where some input selections can cause the data to filter to zero observations for some calculations. This causes a problem when I count observations by week and group and then try to join this resulting dataset into another dataset downstream.

For instance, if the calculation of `dat_2` below filters to zero observations, I get the following with `group_by` and `count()`:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   date, diss_group [1]
  date       diss_group date2_n
  <date>     <fct>        <int>
1 NA         NA               0
```

When I need zero counts by group for the range of weeks:

```
    # A tibble: 22 x 3
   date       diss_group date1_n
   <date>     <chr>        <dbl>
 1 2019-05-15 a                0
 2 2019-05-22 a                0
 3 2019-05-29 a                0
 4 2019-06-05 a                0
 5 2019-06-12 a                0
 6 2019-06-19 a                0
 7 2019-06-26 a                0
 8 2019-07-03 a                0
 9 2019-07-10 a                0
10 2019-07-17 a                0
# … with 12 more rows
```

Here's an example

```
library(tidyverse)

# selecting date range via Shiny input
  start <- "2019-05-15"
  end <- "2019-07-25"
  startdate_adjusted <- ymd(start) - lubridate::floor_date(ymd(start), 
                                                           "1 week")

# generate some data
  dat <- data.frame(date1 = c("2019-05-04",
                              "2019-05-15",
                              "2019-05-18",
                              "2019-05-23",
                              "2019-05-23",
                              "2019-06-10",
                              "2019-06-15",
                              "2019-06-25",
                              "2019-06-26"),
                    date2 = c("2019-05-06",
                              "2019-05-16",
                              NA,
                              NA,
                              "2019-06-06",
                              "2019-06-15",
                              NA,
                              "2019-06-29",
                              "2019-06-29"),
                    Total = as.character(rep("Total", 9)),
                    letter = as.character(c("a", "a", "b",
                                            "a", "a", "b",
                                            "a", "a", "b"))
  )

  dat <-
    dat %>%
    mutate(date1 = ymd(as.character(date1))) %>%
    mutate(date2 = ymd(as.character(date2))) %>%
    mutate(Total = factor(Total, levels="Total")) %>%
    mutate(letter = factor(letter, levels=c("a", "b")))

# count 1
  dat_1 <- 
  dat %>%
    filter(!is.na(date1)) %>%
    mutate(date = date(date1)) %>%
    mutate(diss_group = letter) %>%
    filter(!is.na(diss_group)) %>%
    filter(diss_group!="") %>%
    group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(date, "1 week") + startdate_adjusted,
             diss_group) %>%
    count(name = "date1_n") %>%
    spread(diss_group, date1_n) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    padr::pad(interval = "1 week",
              by = "date",
              start_val = ymd(start),
              end_val = ymd(end)
    ) %>% 
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
    gather("diss_group", "date1_n", -date)

 dat_1
 #   # A tibble: 22 x 3
 #  date       diss_group date1_n
 #  <date>     <chr>        <dbl>
 #1 2019-05-15 a                1
 #2 2019-05-22 a                2
 #3 2019-05-29 a                0
 #4 2019-06-05 a                0
 #5 2019-06-12 a                1
 #6 2019-06-19 a                0
 #7 2019-06-26 a                1
 #8 2019-07-03 a                0
 #9 2019-07-10 a                0
 #10 2019-07-17 a                0
 # … with 12 more rows

# count 2, problem from `filter(letter=="c")` 
  dat_2 <- 
  dat %>%
    filter(!is.na(date2)) %>%
    mutate(date = date(date2)) %>%
    mutate(diss_group = letter) %>%
    filter(!is.na(diss_group)) %>%
    filter(diss_group!="") %>%
    filter(letter=="c") %>%          # letter c does not exist
    group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(date, "1 week") + startdate_adjusted,
             diss_group) %>%
    count(name = "date2_n") %>%
    spread(diss_group, date2_n) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    padr::pad(interval = "1 week",
              by = "date",
              start_val = ymd(start),
              end_val = ymd(end)
    ) %>% 
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
    gather("diss_group", "date2_n", -date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.drop = FALSE` to the `group_by` statement produced:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   date [1]
  date           a     b
  <date>     <int> <int>
1 NA             0     0
```

From here I set `date` equal to `start` if `is.na(date)` with `mutate_if(is.Date, funs(if_else(is.na(.), ymd(start), .)))`

```
dat_2 <- 
dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(date2)) %>%
  mutate(date = date(date2)) %>%
  mutate(diss_group = letter) %>%
  filter(!is.na(diss_group)) %>%
  filter(diss_group!="") %>%
  filter(letter=="c") %>%          # letter c does not exist
  group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(date, "1 week") + startdate_adjusted,
           diss_group, 
           .drop = FALSE) %>%            #### Added 
  count(name = "date2_n") %>%
  spread(diss_group, date2_n) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_if(is.Date, funs(if_else(is.na(.), ymd(start), .))) %>% #### Added
  padr::pad(interval = "1 week",
            by = "date",
            start_val = ymd(start),
            end_val = ymd(end)
  ) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  gather("diss_group", "date2_n", -date)
```

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 3
   date       diss_group date2_n
   <date>     <chr>        <dbl>
 1 2019-05-15 a                0
 2 2019-05-22 a                0
 3 2019-05-29 a                0
 4 2019-06-05 a                0
 5 2019-06-12 a                0
 6 2019-06-19 a                0
 7 2019-06-26 a                0
 8 2019-07-03 a                0
 9 2019-07-10 a                0
10 2019-07-17 a                0
# … with 12 more rows
```